# Help identifying utensil spear

Tags: part-identification

I'm not sure this piece is actually Lego seeing as there is no branding on it.

Note that it looks like some type of spear or arrow.

See picture below (not the minifig) with one in flat silver and the other in chrome silver.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an official LEGO piece. It is called [57467a Minifigure, Weapon Harpoon, 4 Grooves in Shaft](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=39829#T=S&C=22&O=%7B%22color%22:%2222%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) and has been produced for almost 20 years, appearing in [37 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57467c01&in=S).

[image]

Chrome Silver is the common color, Flat Silver (the one on the left in the picture) is the rarer color, only appearing in 1 set - [70800 Getaway Glider from The LEGO Movie](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70800-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) - but this piece is still cheap on BrickLink, so no real value increase despite its rarity.

[image]

Comment: Is there any standard on lego.se as to what sites to link to? I see you linked to bricklink here, but in my Christmas question you linked to brickset.

Comment: There is no standard. The sites linked to are the sites that are considered reputable LEGO reference sites, which include Bricklink, Brickset, Peeron, BrickOwl (rarely), Rebrickable, Brickpicker and Brickipedia (lego.fandom.com, rarely used as reference).